# Extract Datas from Timetable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a timetable consisting of classes that I could take on what day, time and school year. Example below:[image]

What I want to do is extract the datas: School Year, Semester, Class ID, Class Name, Teacher, Class Room and include the Day and Period of Time as well. And then create a new table using the extracted datas. Example below:[image]

I wanted to ask if there is a faster and easier way to do this using a formula or VBA. Right now, all I am doing is copying and pasting, but there are so many data. (Monday to Friday and 1st Period to 6th Period )

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible via VBA, but your sheet's structure is not completely visible in that screenshot: It doesn't show were "1st Period" will end and "2nd Period" will begin.

For the rest of the data except `Time`, the following function will do what you want. It extracts data from a sheet named `Sheet1` to a sheet named `Sheet2`.

```
Sub extractData()

    ' Keep track of day name
    DayName = ""

    ' Loop variable
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    loopVar = True

    While (loopVar)

        ' Get the Class ID
        ClassID = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value

        ' Check if this is an empty row
        If (ClassID <> "") Then

            ' Get the semester name
            Sem = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value

            ' Get the Class Name
            ClassName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value

            ' Get the Teacher Name
            TeacherName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Value

            ' Get the Class Room
            ClassRoom = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & i).Value

            ' Get the day name
            Temp = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
            If Temp <> "" Then DayName = Temp

            j = i - 2

            ' Set the Class ID
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j).Value = ClassID

            ' Set the Class Name
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & j).Value = ClassName

            ' Set the Teacher
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & j).Value = TeacherName

            ' Set the Class Room
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & j).Value = ClassRoom

            ' Set the semester
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & j).Value = Sem

            ' Set the Day Name
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & j).Value = DayName

            ' Incrementl the loop variable
            i = i + 1

        Else

            ' End the loop
            loopVar = False

        End If

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way 2nd period starts after the column "Class Room". It is basically a copy of 1st Period (Semester to Class Room) .

Comment: Yes it works but partially. When I ran it, it only made a table of the subject "English I". The rest is missing

Comment: @syn3rgy: I've updated the code. The number of items in the Class ID column were not getting calculated correctly because of merged rows. Let me know if it works now. (If you can post a link to your excel file it would be best to test the code on it)

Comment: I was testing your new code but all I get is compile error : Next without For. I will also try to put an example file if possible, It has some sensitive data that I would like to keep private.

Comment: @synergy: Sorry for so many iterations, but it really becomes impossible to write a program without data. I've corrected the code above as per your input.

Comment: no problem .. sorry that I cant really post the data, but thanks for the help anyway. By the way, the code above still gives me a compile error: Syntax error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127975/discussion-between-nvj-and-syn3rgy).